# Tableau Customised FIlter

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, tableau-api

Below is the screenshot of the visualization that I have been working on.

[image]

I need a small help/advice/guidance regarding one Customised filter.

A small detail on the X and Y axis of the graph. X axis contains distinct DRG Codes while Y axis contains its respective average cost. The color indicates the 4 severity levels (1,2,3,4). 0 is null.

I need to filter and keep only those data which are above that Average mark in Grey. I need the filter to work for all the Severitys at the same time, like the AND operator. You can see such an example for 1,2,3,4,5 DRG Codes. There all the severities are above the average mark. I wrote something like -

`IF [APR Severity Of Illness Code]==1 AND [MeanCost.mean]>29863 THEN [MeanCost.mean]
    END + IF [APR Severity Of Illness Code]==2 AND [MeanCost.mean]>29863 THEN [MeanCost.mean]
    END + IF [APR Severity Of Illness Code]==3 AND [MeanCost.mean]>29863 THEN [MeanCost.mean]
    END + IF [APR Severity Of Illness Code]==4 AND [MeanCost.mean]>29863 THEN [MeanCost.mean]
    END`

which obviously didnt work out. 
It works when only one condition is given, something like -

```
IF [APR Severity Of Illness Code]==1 AND [MeanCost.mean]>29863 THEN [MeanCost.mean]
END
```

but the filter returns null values when more than one condition is given. Please help.

Comment: So your just going to pull this straight into the filter? Its not going to be a user selected filter? Why do you need an IF statement if the MeanCost.mean level(29863) is the same for all severity's? If its to stay in this way I would think you need to use an IFELSE statement rather then closing every IF you ("END")have and starting another.

Comment: I have used what Bernardo suggested in the answer below. Couldnt get it to work. 

I didnt use IFELSE because I need it to work at the same time. I mean, it is not either this or that. It should be AND in all the cases. 

I need to display all the DRGCodes which have all the severities greater than the avg mean cost.

Answer (score 0):

You probably only need one IF statement.

```
If [MeanCost.mean] > {fixed : avg([MeanCost.mean]) } then 'show' else 'hide' END
```

Create a new calculation as well for a new reference line, this is calculation2 in the sample workbook.

```
{fixed : avg([MeanCost.mean]) }
```

This is because if you filter out the "hide" values, your current reference line will move to show the average of all your "show" values.

Now place your filter and select 'show'.

Sample attached. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60455118/POC%20Req%203%20-%2023%20Sept.twbx

Comment: Here is what I did - 
1. Made a calculation field.
2. Inserted what you told, including the 'show' and no syntax error.
3. Added that to the Filter shelf.

Here is what happened. 
Select from List shows Null value. If I click Ok, no filtering is done and all the values remain the same. 

Your code makes full sense but somehow I am not being able to make it work.

Comment: Here is the Drive link for the same -
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2zFuMt6Wn9lZVh1VGlPcjRudDQ

Please check the Calculation1 in Measures.

Answer (score 0):

**pragyanbezbo**, assuming you have Tableau v9 or v10, you could use Level of Detail (LOD) expressions introduced in version 9 last year:

```
{ FIXED [APR DRG Code], [APR Severity Of Illness Code] : AVG([MeanCost.mean]) } > 29863
```

This should return TRUE/FALSE and work just fine. I'd maybe suggest replacing the hard-coded mean value (29,863) with dynamic formula using LOD, but I am not sure how the filters are applied and it would probably require some more details to get it right, but I think this should be enough to point you in a right direction.

Here is the link to [LOD Overview](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html). And some *Jedi LOD* [examples](http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2016/1/lods-fun-jedi-filters-48123). Hope this helps.